# Join tables with mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

table A (tracks):

```
track_name1 |   link    |   age |   artists
track_name2 |   link    |   age |   here
track_name3 |   link    |   age |   but
track_name4 |   link    |   age |   how?
```

Table B (artists):

```
jon     |   nick    |   age
mark    |   nick    |   age
luke    |   nick    |   age
you     |   nick    |   age
```

I'd like to get 
 track "1" --> artist "Jon and mark" and get all other info about them.
Thanks!

Comment: Please post your table definitions (column names + data types) and primary keys for both tables. We can't help without that information.

Comment: You need to learn about Primary and Secondary keys and about `JOIN`.

Comment: what is determining that jon and mark are on track 1?

Comment: Hi Can you post the actual Table structures that you are using ? The one you mentioned above is only values. We need the field names as well. So its best you post a screenshot of the table structures and let us know the expected result.

Comment: You'll need a third table, not an artists column. "many-to-many relationship"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments of @Uueerdo. You need a third table which maps the tracks and artists together. Please see the below code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tracks` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `link` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tracks` (`id`, `name`, `link`, `age`) VALUES
   ('1', 'track_name1', 'link1', '25'),
   ('2', 'track_name2', 'link2', '25'),
   ('3', 'track_name3', 'link3', '35'),
   ('4', 'track_name4', 'link4', '35');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artists` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `nick_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `artists` (`id`, `name`, `nick_name`, `age`) VALUES
    ('1', 'jon', 'jon', '25'),
    ('2', 'mark', 'mark', '25'),
    ('3', 'luke', 'luke', '35'),
    ('4', 'you', 'you', '35');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tracks_artists` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `track_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tracks_artists` (`id`, `track_id`, `artist_id`) VALUES
    ('1', '1', '1'),
    ('2', '2', '2'),
    ('3', '3', '3'),
    ('4', '4', '4’);
```

And then you can run the below mentioned query to get the above mentioned results:

```
SELECT `t2`.`name`, `t2`.`link`, `t2`.`age`, `t3`.`name`
FROM `tracks_artists` `t1` 
INNER JOIN `tracks` `t2` ON `t1`.`track_id` = `t2`.`id`
INNER JOIN `artists` `t3` ON `t1`.`artist_id` = `t3`.`id`;
```

I have made the code available [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba1635/1). You can test it out.

Hope this helps.